# Java Arraylist got java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, outbound

I'm a general 3D artist, switched from my career and started to learn programming.
I've got a problem with c106a handout #5.

The code works, but I've still got some error log here.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4
at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
at UniqueNames.showUnique(UniqueNames.java:23)
at UniqueNames.main(UniqueNames.java:39)
```

Why does `Arraylist`, which can stretch its capacity on its own, still get an `OutOfBoundsException`?

Here's my full code:

```
import acm.io.*;
import acm.program.ConsoleProgram;
import acm.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.*;

public class UniqueNames extends ConsoleProgram{

  static ArrayList<String> meString = new ArrayList<String>();
  static String input ;

    public static void storeUnique(String input){
        if (!meString.contains(input))
           {
            meString.add(input);
            }
    }

    public static void showUnique(ArrayList<String> meString){
        System.out.println("Unique name list contains:");
        for(int i=0 ;i<= meString.size() ;i++){
            System.out.println(meString.get(i));
          }
      }

    public static void main(String[] args){

             try{
                InputStreamReader stream = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(stream);
                   while (true){
                       System.out.println("Enter name:");
                       String input = br.readLine();
                       if (input.equals("")) break;
                       storeUnique(input);
                      }  

                  {showUnique(meString);}  
                }
             catch(IOException e){
                }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

The following lines:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= meString.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(meString.get(i));
}
```

should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < meString.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(meString.get(i));
}
```

This is because the index of the list starts from zero.

`Index: 4, Size: 4` explains a little more. When you call `get(4)`, an exception occurs because your list only has a size of 4. `get(4)` would attempt to access the 5th element in the list.

Valid elements you can access would be `get(0)`, `get(1)`, `get(2)`, `get(3)`.

Answer (score 6):

Use the above answer, or you can use a [foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work):

```
for (String str: meString) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You asked, "Why does Arraylist, which can stretch its capacity by its own still get an OutOfBoundsException ???"
The answer is: an ArrayList only stretches its capacity when:

1. You add an object to it ( `.add(Object o)` ).
2. You add the contents of another collection to it ( `.addAll(Collection c)` ).
3. You ensure its size  ( `.ensureCapacity(int minCapacity)` ).

The trouble you're having is that you are trying to access an object in an index of the list that doesn't exist.  While an ArrayList will dynamically resize when you **change** the contents, it won't do it when you are simply trying to **access** the contents.
That is the difference.
To avoid accessing an index that doesn't exist:

1. Take Surresh Atta's suggestion: Use `i < meString.size()` instead of `i <= meString.size()` because the index starts with 0 instead of 1.
2. Take Ankit's suggestion and just use the enhanced for loop: `for(String str : meString)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a 2D ArrayList ,make sure you instantiate every row and every element of the corresponding row using the following code:

```
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        p.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            p.get(i).add(new Integer(0));
        }
    }
```

This creates an ArrayList with i (=n) rows and each row contains an ArrayList with j (=n) number of elements.

If instantiation is  not done properly it might result in an IndexOutOfBoundsException