# Making string contain method

Tags: java, string, methods

Im trying to do this programme

> int contains(String s1, String s2): receives two strings, and
>   checks whether s2 is in s1 case sensitively. If s2 is in s1 it returns the index of the last occurrence of s2, otherwise it returns -1.

Here is an example

```
Enter first string: O pikap, su pikap, bu pikap.
Enter second string: pikap
22
Enter first string: O pikap, su pikap, bu pikap.
Enter second string: pikapcik
-1
```

I've written the codes but gave me an error like this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
   at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
   at Test.main(Test.java:12)**
```

Why there is such an error and how do i fix this?
Im only allowed use charAt and length methods

Here is the code

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String b1 = "O pikap, su pikap, bu pikap";
    String a1 = "pikap";
    String sum = "";
    int b =b1.length();
    int a =a1.length();
    for( ; b>0 ; b--){
        b = b - a;
        for(int n = 0; n < a ; n++ , b++){
            sum+= b1.charAt(b);
        }
        if(sum == a1)
            break;   
    }//for 1
    System.out.println(b-a+1);
}
```

Comment: You fix this by not doing `b1.charAt(-1)`..

Comment: Homework alert.

Comment: Try looking [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446302/java-arraylist-got-java-lang-indexoutofboundsexception) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21570318/understand-arraylist-indexoutofboundsexception-in-android) or any of the other hundreds of duplicates on this site.

Comment: Also note that strings **must** be checked for equality with `equals` not `==`

Answer (score 0):

because in loop for each decrements it's increasing for whole character and then StringIndexOutOfBoundsException exception occurs
check b-- and b++ condition below:

```
for( ; b>0 ; b--){
    b = b - a;
for(int n = 0; n < a ; n++ , b++){
    sum+= b1.charAt(b);
}
if(sum == a1)
break;         }//for 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Uhm.. read documenation on the String object before starting on custom objects.

```
    String b1 = "O pikap, su pikap, bu pikap";
    String a1 = "pikap";
    System.out.println( b1.lastIndexOf(a1)  );
```

If you need to know how it works

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.lastIndexOf%28char%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%2Cchar%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%29

Comment: im not allowed to use indexOf methdod

Comment: You did not mention that in your question, update your question with the specifics of the limitations that were put to you.

Answer (score 0):

You should stop the loop if int b is smaller than int a. When int b is decreased to 4 in the first loop the result of the operation b = b-a; means b = -1 and in second loop it checks b1.charAt(-1) and there is no -1. index of string b1. btw you can simply use str.lastIndexOf().